# ¿Es esto problema de tener varios .subscribe en cadena en Angular?

Tags: angular

Cuando el usuario realiza el pago del producto/s se debería crear en este orden:

1. la orden.
2. el detalle de la orden.
3. la venta.
4. detalle de venta.

De la forma que lo estoy haciendo funciona, es decir los datos se guardan en la base de datos pero por consola estoy viendo que los procesos no se cumplen en el orden establecido o de forma sincronizada, es decir por consola veo los mensajes en el siguiente orden:

1. La orden fue creada exitosamente.
2. La venta fue creada.
3. El detalle de la orden fue creada exitosamente.
4. el detalle de venta fue creado.

Pero esto no estaría mal?, ya que una vez creada la orden deberia crearse el detalle de la orden, ya teniendo estos dos procesos realizados
deberia crearse la venta y por ultimo el detalle de la venta según mi código.
Explicando la lógica de mi codigo lo que hice fue: una funcion `createOrder()` que implementa el servicio para crear la orden, me **subscribo**, si esta todo bien aviso que la que la orden fue creada y ejecuto la funcion  `createOrderDetail()` implementando el servicio para crear el detalle de la orden.
Por otro lado tengo la función `createSale()` que implementa el servicio para crear la venta, me **subscribo**, si esta todo bien aviso que la venta fue creada y ejecuto la funcion `createSaleDetail()` implementando el servicio para crear el detalle de la venta.
Cuando el usuario pulsa el **botón pagar**, se hace el pago con `Stripe` (modo de prueba), si Stripe no devuelve error se ejecuta `createOrder()` y `createSale()`.

Aca en `Angular` `order.component.ts`

Aca la funcion `pagar()` cuando el usuario hace la compra

```js
async pagar(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(this.card);
      if (token) {
        await this.stripeService.charge(1, token.id).then(
          res => {
            console.log('el pago fue realizado');
            this.createOrder();
            this.createSale();
            // redirigir a view con mensaje muchas gracias por su compra !
            this.router.navigate(['purchase-completed']);
          },
          err => console.error('Falla al intentar pagar')
        );   
      } else {
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.cardError = error.message);
        alert('No se pudo efectuar el pago');
      }

    }
  }

createOrder() {
    this.order.id_user = 1;
    this.order.order_date = this.currentDate;
    this.order.total_price = this.total;
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.order).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('La orden fue creada exitosamente');
        // se crea el detalle de la orden
        this.createOrderDetail();
      },
      err => console.error('No se pudo crear la orden ' + err.error.message)
    );
  }
  
createOrderDetail() {
    // antes de crear el detalle de la orden traigo el ultimo id_order de la tabla "orders" de la base de datos
    let idOrder;
    this.orderService.getLastIdOrder().subscribe(
      res => {
        idOrder = res;
        console.log('Ultimo idOrder obtenido: ' + idOrder.lastIdOrder);
        for (const item of this.bookList) {
          this.orderDetail.id_order = idOrder.lastIdOrder;
          this.orderDetail.id_product = item.id_book;
          this.orderDetail.product_price = item.price;
          this.orderDetail.product_quantity = 1; // hacer que en frontend elija cantidad
          // se crea el detalle de la orden de compra
          this.orderDetailService.createOrderDetail(this.orderDetail).subscribe(
            resp => {
              console.log('El detalle de la orden fue creada exitosamente ' + resp);
            },
            err => console.error('No se pudo crear el detalle de la orden ' + err.error.message)
          );
        }
      },
      err => console.error('Error al intentar obtener el ultimo idOrder de la base de datos')
    );
  }


createSale() {
    this.sale.id_user = 1;
    this.sale.total_price = this.total;
    this.sale.date = this.currentDate;
    this.saleServices.createSale(this.sale).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('La venta fue creada');
        this.createSaleDetail();
      },
      err => console.error('No se pudo crear la venta ' + err.error.message)
    );
  }
  
 createSaleDetail() {
    let idSale;
    // antes de crear el detalle de venta, necesito obtener el id de la venta creada
    this.saleServices.getLastIdSale().subscribe(
      res => {
        idSale = res;
        console.log('Ultimo idSale obtenido: ' + idSale.lastIdSale);
        // se crea el detalle de la venta
        for (const item of this.bookList) {
          this.saleDetail.id_book = item.id_book;
          this.saleDetail.id_sale = idSale.lastIdSale;
          this.saleDetail.price = item.price;
          this.saleDetail.quantity = 1;
          this.saleDetailServices.createSaleDetail(this.saleDetail).subscribe(
            resp => {
              console.log('El detalle de venta fue creado ' + resp);
            },
            err => console.error('No se pudo crear el detalle de venta ' + err.error.message)
          );
        }
      },
      err => console.error('No se pudo obtener el último id de venta ' + err.error.message)
    );
  }
```

**Aca todos los servicios**

**order.service.ts**

```js
createOrder(order: Order){
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/orders/create', order);
}

getLastIdOrder() {
  return this.http.get<number>('http://localhost:4000/orders/lastIdOrder');
}
```

**order-detail.services.ts**

```js
createOrderDetail(orderDetail: OrderDetail){
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/ordersDetail/create', orderDetail);
}
```

**sale.services.ts**

```js
createSale(sale: Sale){
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/sales/create', sale);
}

getLastIdSale() {
  return this.http.get<number>('http://localhost:4000/sales/lastIdSale');
}
```

**sale-detail.service.ts**

```js
createSaleDetail(saleDetail: SaleDetail){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/salesDetail/create', saleDetail);
  }
```

Comment: Te pudiera recomendar ver un poco de Rxjs que ayuda bastante para mantener las peticiones asincronas al igual que la programacion reactiva.

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo simultáneamente y en paralelo dos peticiones. Cada una de ellas, al completarse, realiza una segunda petición:

```
     / createOrder -> createOrderDetail
pagar
     \ createSale  -> createSaleDetail
```

Si las dependencias son éstas (no hay depencia entre orden y venta), no hay ningún problema. Lo único que está pasando es que ambas ramas se ejecutan en paralelo y nada asegura qué rama será completada antes.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Pablo Lozano. De que forma puedo hacer que al terminar de relizarse el detalle de la orden se ejecute la venta y despues detalle de venta, es decir que haya dependencia. Antiguamente en el subscribe de orders_detail ejecutaba la funcion para crear la venta, el problema estaba por ej en que si el detalle de la orden constaba de 3 productos, la venta se creaba 3 veces, por esa razón el createSale lo hice aparte.